# How to mock AWS DynamoDB if multiple GetItem() in flow?

Tags: unit-testing, go, amazon-dynamodb

eventHandler.go

```
func eventHandler(Id) error {
    eventDetails, err := GetEventStore(svc.Connection.DynamoDBClient, Id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("Error while reading Store", err)
        return err
    }
    if eventDetails.status == "completed" {
        config, err := GetConfig(svc.Connection.DynamoDBClient, Key)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("Error while reading Config Store", err)
            return err
        }
        // process it
    }
  return nil
}
```

Most of our data is stored in stores so while writing unit tests for eventHandler how to mockDynamoDB with multiple GetItemOutput ?

eventHnadler_test.go

```
...
eventDetails := {
 //data
}
config := {
//data
}
        DB := client.DynamoDBClient{
            Client: mockDynamoDB{
                Output: dynamodb.GetItemOutput{
                    Item: eventDetails,
                },
                Error: tc.Error,
            },
        }
...
```

Can multiple get calls be mocked in GO aws sdk v2?

Comment: you need to filter them by the inputs

Comment: do you mind explaining with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func (m mockDynamodb) GetItem(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.GetItemInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.GetItemOutput, error) { 
 if (params.tablename == “eventDetails”) {     
  return m.eventDetailsItemOutput, m.clientError 
 } else {     
  return m.configItemOutput, m.clientError 
 } 
}
```

In test file

```
DB := client.DynamoDBClient{
 Client: mockDynamoDB{
   eventDetailsItemOutput: dynamodb.GetItemOutput{
     Item: eventDetails,
   },
   configItemOutput: dynamodb.GetItemOutput{
     Item: eventDetails,
   },
   Error: tc.Error,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because AWS dynamo DB got restructured so

`github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/dynamodbiface` doesn't exists anymore you have to implement your own interface to have proper dynamo mocking

your **Wrapper** around aws implentation should be something similar like that

```
type Dynamodb struct {
    Client  DynamoAPI
}

type DynamoAPI interface {
        GetItem(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.GetItemInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.GetItemOutput, error)
        UpdateItem(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.UpdateItemInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.UpdateItemOutput, error)
        PutItem(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.PutItemInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.PutItemOutput, error)
        DeleteItem(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.DeleteItemInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.DeleteItemOutput, error)
        Query(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.QueryInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.QueryOutput, error)
        Scan(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.ScanInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.ScanOutput, error)
    }
```

and here could be your mocks

```
type mockDynamodb struct {
    rbaws.DynamoAPI
    *dynamodb.Client
    clientError error
}

func (m mockDynamodb) GetItem(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.GetItemInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.GetItemOutput, error) {

    return &dynamodb.GetItemOutput{
        Item: map[string]types.AttributeValue{},
    }, m.clientError
}
```

Comment: yes correct, but i am making 2 `GetItem` calls in my `eventHandler(Id)` function and so we can set only 1 `GetItem` call data right - `Item: eventDetails` but for 2nd call it will return the eventDetails again instead of configDetails as output Item is having hardcoded value. Any idea how to set different output data on `GetItem` call?

Comment: Is this the proper way or some other way exist? @mooga
`func (m mockDynamodb) GetItem(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.GetItemInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.GetItemOutput, error) {
if (params.tablename == “eventDetails”) {
    return &dynamodb.GetItemOutput{
        Item: eventDetails,
    }, m.clientError
}
else {
    return &dynamodb.GetItemOutput{
        Item: configDetails,
    }, m.clientError
}
}`

Comment: I am not able to see clear but in general `params.TableName ` and yes i would change my response based on the request attrribuites